# AWS EC2 Linux Instance - Suitable folder location to store a file which is frequently updated and read by the web server

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, amazon-ec2, server

I use AWS EC2 Linux instance, where my tomcat Java based web server is deployed.

My server need to frequently read and write a group of "text files". And these files shouldn't be over written each time I deploy a new version of WAR file. ( Means , even after new war file deployed, the existing text files should be kept as it is )

Please suggest the suitable file location in EC instance, from where the web server can frequently access at the same time, the folder data is untouched with restart or with the deployment of new version of war.

[image: AWS EC2 instance Folder structure]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is a different user running Tomcat (i.e. a `tomcat` user) I would put the files in that users home directory.  It *should* be as easy as accessing the files with something like:

```
File file = new File( System.getProperty("user.home") + "/somedir/file.txt" );
```

The directory should already exist and be owned by the same user as Tomcat is running as.

One caveat is that, depending on your EC2 file system, it may be harder to recreate your environment in the event of a machine crash.  You'll need to make sure that the directory in which you store your files is somehow backed up.  Storing on EFS will help but may not be enough.  Longer term you might want to think about a database of some sort.